# reactjs add multiple card in a row

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

Hi I would like to know how to add multiple Card in a row (i.e let's say 4 or 5). Right now I only have one Card displaying.

[image]

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { Grid, Card, Icon, Image , Button} from 'semantic-ui-react'


export default class Class extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      news:[],
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {

 const  url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=d5cf45043cd34b59b432df10e3cef274';


  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({
        news: data.articles
      })
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      console.log('error while trying to retrieve data')
    })
}

renderItems(){
  const src = 'https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch'
  return this.state.news.map((item) =>(
    <Card.Group>
      <Card
        image={src}
        header='Elliot Baker'
        meta='Friend'
        description='Elliot is a sound engineer living in Nashville who enjoys playing guitar and hanging with his cat.'
      />
    </Card.Group>

  ));
}


    render() {
        return (
          <Grid.Row>
            {this.renderItems()}
          </Grid.Row>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you trying creating a CSS class to using Flex and Flex Wrap?

Comment: This is a css problem. either use flex or make the card container inline-block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of rendering separate cards inside of a group, you are rendering multiple groups with only one card in them. If you update your `renderItems()` method it will work. Using the Array method of map, we now have access to all of the data for each item from your state in a variable called `card`:

```
renderItems = () => {

  return (
    <Card.Group> 
      {this.state.news.map((card) => (
        <Card
          key={card.id} // Make sure you use a unique key identifier for React
          image={card.imageUrl} // This is the url of the image for the current object inside this.state.news.YOUR_CURRENT_OBJECT
          header={card.title}
          meta={card.type}
          description={card.description}
        />
      )}
    </Card.Group>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

```
renderItems(){
  return this.state.news.map((item) =>(
    <Card.Group>
      <Card
        image={item.urlToImage}
        header={item.author}
        meta={item.url}
        description={item.description}
      />
    </Card.Group>
  ));
}
```